# Can't embed contents using iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Here is the short simple HTML5 code that defines my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <iframe src="2.html" width="450" height="350"> </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I have triple-checked that file *2.html* exists in the same directory, and it has some code in it. I have cleared caches and history in my browser, but observed no page embedded. I have tried this in Chrome, Firefox and IE too, but am getting nothing. I just got the iframe box with border, that's completely white (blank). What's wrong with it?

Comment: Check the devtools network tab to see the downloading status of 2.html.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If not, try comparing with [this plunker example](http://embed.plnkr.co/uVkPx1XqJ9Q05yJbIbti/).

Comment: What do you have in `2.html`?